# Swift - JSON array values

Tags: json, swift

I am getting following JSON values in output:

```
[["category_title": Shelly], ["category_title": Thaddeus],
["category_title": Chantale], ["category_title": Adara],
["category_title": Mariko], ["category_title": Felicia]]
```

But I want it like below:

```
["Shelly","Thaddeus","Chantale", "Adara","Mariko","Felicia"]
```

I have the following Swift code. Please help me get above output.

```
func successGetTermsData(response: Any){
    var UserRole : String = ""
    var arrayOfDetails = response as? [[String: Any]] ?? []

    UserRole = arrayOfDetails as? String ?? ""
    print(arrayOfDetails)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no "" signs around the names as well? That doesn't seem like a proper JSON to me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `map` the array of `Dictionary` `arrayOfDetails` to an array of `String`. `flatMap` ignores a missing key.

```
if let arrayOfDetails = response as? [[String: String]] {
    let userRole = arrayOfDetails.flatMap { $0["category_title"] }
    print(userRole)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. One way is to use flatmap to get just the values in your array of dictionaries:

```
let arrayOfValues = arrayOfDetails.flatMap { $0.values }
```

In order to get this to work, the names need to be inside double quotes: "Shelly", etc.